# Flip a coin until getting HTH

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I am tossing a coin with probability $p$ of heads (H) and $q=1-p$ of tails (T). What is the expected number of tosses until I get HTH?

The book that I am reading suggests the following solution: consider the event that HTH does not occur in $n$ tosses, and in addition the next three tosses give HTH. If we look at the combinations of the $(n-1)$-th and $n$-th tosses, followed by HTH, we can deduce that:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(Y>n)p^2q=\mathbb{P}(Y=n+1)pq+\mathbb{P}(Y=n+3),\quad n\geq 2
\end{equation} 
As suggested, it is possible to sum this equation over $n$ in order to obtain that $\mathbb{E}(Y)=(pq+1)/(p^2q)$. However, I tried to do the sum and manipulate it in different ways but I could not obtain anything that leads me to this conclusion.

Comment: I suppose that $m$ is supposed to be $n$?

Comment: yes, thanks, I will edit it.

Comment: That equation and $E(Y)=(pq+1)/p^2 q$ are not compatible: summation over $n$ gives $E(Y)p^2 q = pq + 1 - P(Y=3) - P(Y=4)$ which would imply $E(Y)>(pq+1)/p^2 q$. There must be some error in the formulation of the equation. Doing some reverse engineering, the solution would go through if that equation were to hold for $n \geq 0$; then summation over $n$ would give the given result. But I cannot really follow the derivation of the equation anyway, so I don't see how to get this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a Markov Chain (MC) whose states are:

$S_0$: no flip (initial state), or the only flip was a T, or the last two flips were TT;

$S_1$: the last flip was an H;

$S_2$: the last two flips were HT;

$S_3$: the last three flips were HTH.

These states and the transitions between them are represented in the figure below:
[image]

Such MC induce a partition of the possible strings. Let $m_{i,j}$ be the expected number of flips needed to visit state $j$ for the first time after departing from state $i$. We can write the following system of linear equations:
\begin{equation}
m_{0,3}=1+q.m_{0,3}+p.m_{1,3}\\
m_{1,3}=1+p.m_{1,3}+q.m_{2,3}\\
m_{2,3}=1+p.m_{3,3}+q.m_{0,3}\\
m_{3,3}=0
\end{equation}
Where the first equation means that the expected number of flips to reach state $S_3$ from state $S_0$ is one flip plus whatever number is needed after this flip: with probability $q$, this flip resulted in a T, the state is again $S_0$ and the remaining expected number to reach $S_3$ continues to be the same; and, with probability $p$, this flip resulted in an H, the state becomes $S_1$, and the remaining expected number is the analogous number needed for going from $S_1$ to $S_3$. The other equations are built similarly.

Solving this system of equations and doing some mechanic algebra, we obtain $m_{0,3}=(pq+1)/(p^2q)$ as proposed.

I think that this solution is simple enough, however I could not check how this relates to the demonstration suggested by the book that I mentioned in the question.

Comment: That's another nice approach, which involves a bit more delicate setup but less calculation in the end. You can get something similar by "compressing" the state space of my approach by identification of "equivalent" states. For example, from the perspective of getting to HTH, THT and HHT are the same state, so they may be identified. This "compressed" version of my approach is not quite the same as yours, however, because your approach explicitly models the first three flips rather than building them into the initial distribution.

Comment: To be specific, one may compress my approach by identifying THH with HHH; THT with HHT; and HTT with TTT. HTH and TTH of course cannot be identifed. So my approach can have its state space reduced to 5 states instead of 8.

Answer (score 4):

The method I like for this kind of problem is to set up a Markov chain. Here the state space is the last three coin flips that we saw. We set the initial distribution to be the usual distribution on 3 biased coin flips (a sequence containing $k$ heads has probability $p^k q^{3-k}$). Then we use a standard "renewal argument":

$$E[\tau_{HTH} \mid X_0=i] = \sum_{j \in S} (1+E[\tau_{HTH} \mid X_0=j]) p_{ij} = 1 + \sum_{j \in S} E[\tau_{HTH} \mid X_0=j] p_{ij}$$

This is just saying that if  we start at $i$, we go to a new state $j$, that takes one flip, and then we add in the average number of flips it's going to take us to get from $j$, weighted by how likely it was to go to $j$. Finally we adjoin the boundary condition $E[\tau_{HTH} \mid X_0=HTH]=0$. So one of our seven other equations will be

$$E[\tau_{HTH} \mid X_0=HHH]=1+p E[\tau_{HTH} \mid X_0=HHH]+ q E[\tau_{HTH} \mid X_0=HHT].$$

Solving this whole system of linear equations, left-multiplying the resulting column vector by the row vector of the initial distribution, and then adding $3$ (to take into account the initial three flips) gives the desired result.

This approach is quite flexible; for example it can be used to understand the surprising differences between "HHT" and "HTT".

Comment: It puzzles me that the MC states that you propose do not model the initial states of the system. I actually made the calculations as you suggest and it does not agree with the solution suggested in the book.

Comment: @IRO What do you mean that it doesn't model the initial states? I condition on the first three flips, compute the expectation under each of the eight possible conditions, and then I average the results (since the eight initial strings are all equally likely) and add 3. When I do this I get an answer of 10 (with p=q). What answer do you get? It seems likely that you just made an error in setting up the transition probability matrix.

Comment: @IRO I also tried direct simulation and I get a similar result; doing 1000 Monte Carlo iterations gave me an average number of flips of 10.162 (again with p=q).

Comment: Indeed your numeric result agrees with the formula given above. My question regards exactly what you just explained: what if p<>q? I suppose that I would have to determine the probability of each initial state as ppp, ppq, pqp, etc., and compose the row vector that multiplies the solution of the system, correct? This sounds reasonable to me, however when I solved the system it resulted in a too big expression that I could not manipulate further. Perhaps I made some mistake, but if you can give some hint how to simplify the resolution (perhaps using a solver), it would be of great help.

Comment: @IRO Do you really need a closed form solution for the expectation? It seems to me that this closed form could be quite complicated.

Comment: This was my goal, although your explanation opened my eyes to another way of resolution. I have just find out another demonstration, which I will post here soon. Thanks so far!